# Error Ajax and Laravel 500 (Internal Sever Error)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm attempting to use AJAX in Chrome, but it's not working. This is my code, which you can see below. This is a copy of my web.php file.

```
Route::view('menu','home.menu',['categories'=> App\Categories::orderBy('name')->get()->take(11),'active' => 'menu'])->name('menu');
Route::get('/products','MenuController@getproducts');
```

This is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType:'html',
      url: "{{url('/products')}}",
      data: "cat_id="+ id,
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        $("#productData").html(response)
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
      },
    });
```

This is the code for my controller method.

```
    public static function getproducts(Request $request)
    {
        get productsd = $request->cat_id;
        $categories = Categories::orderBy('name')->get()->take(11);
        $collection = DB::table('products')
                      ->join('product_category', 'products.id','=', 'product_category.product_id')
                      ->where('product_category.category_id', '=', $category_id)
                      ->get();
        return view('home.menu',[
            'data' => $collection,
        ]);
    }
```

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: Undefined variable: categories (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/shop/resources/views/home/menu.blade.php) in file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/shop/resources/views/home/menu.blade.php on line 28
```

Comment: return view('home.menu',[
            'data' => $collection,
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One change you can do is in Ajax for below line.

```
data: "cat_id="+ id,
```

So better to pass

```
data: {cat_id:id}
```

you are not using received `category id` from `request`  in your query while returning view ,you are not passing categories

```
return view('home.menu',[
            'data' => $collection,
            'categories'=>$categories
        ]);
```